# Reading and Flattening PySpark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark application that reads data from S3 bucket in ORC format, I also extracted the Avro schema from Confluent Kafka Schema Registry and converted to Spark Schema using a separate function as below:

```
def avro_to_pyspark_type(type_str):
    if isinstance(type_str, dict) and "logicalType" in type_str:
        if type_str["logicalType"] == "date":
            return IntegerType()
        elif type_str["logicalType"] == "timestamp-millis":
            return LongType()
        elif type_str["logicalType"] == "decimal":
            return DecimalType()
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported Avro logical type: {type_str['logicalType']}")
    elif type_str == "string":
        return StringType()
    elif type_str == "int":
        return IntegerType()
    elif type_str == "double":
        return DoubleType()
    elif type_str == "boolean":
        return BooleanType()
    elif type_str == "long":
        return LongType()
    elif type_str == "bytes":
        return BinaryType()
    elif type_str == "null":
        return NullType()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported data type: {type_str}")


def avro_schema_to_pyspark_schema(avro_schema):
    '''
    This function takes Avro Schema from 
    Schema Registry and returns Spark Schema
    '''
    fields = avro_schema["fields"]
    struct_fields = []
    
    for field in fields:
        field_name = field["name"]
        field_type = field["type"]
        
        if isinstance(field_type, list):
            pyspark_type = avro_to_pyspark_type(field_type[1])
        else:
            pyspark_type = avro_to_pyspark_type(field_type)
        struct_fields.append(StructField(field_name, pyspark_type, nullable=True))
    return StructType(struct_fields)
```

### the ORC dataframe is in the following format:

key | content

---

The content column includes actual records in json-like format which I need to flatten them
I use the following code snippet also to read and flatten dataframe:

```
spark_schema = avro_schema_to_pyspark_schema(avro_schema_from_registry)

df = spark.read.format('orc').load("s3a://bucket/test.snappy.orc")
    
# Flattening DataFrame
df = df.withColumn("Content", from_json(col("Content"), spark_schema))
flattened_df = df.select("Content.*")
```

The code is working fine using Spark 3 but when I use spark 2.4 on the server it returns Null value for all the records, I'd appreciate for any help on this.

Comment: It's most probably a problem of your `spark_schema`. Try with a in-line simpler schema to see whether it works (you can add just 1 field to `from_json` and ignore others) and then keep adding more until you find which one is causing problems.